# How to convert variables into json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to send json data to ajax but how do you convert variables into json or convert an array to json?

```
$(".confirm_order").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var street = $("#street").val();
    var location = $("#location").val();
    var number = $("#number").val();

    var f = ???

            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "/orders",
            dataType: "json",
            data: f,
            success: function (l) { 
                alert("Done");
            }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really want to convert the data into JSON, you have to create an object or array and use `JSON.stringify` (available in newer browser and can be loaded form [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/)):

```
var f = JSON.stringify({street: street, location: location, number: number});
```

but you cannot just set the `data` attribute to `f` then. You have to assign it to another variable:

```
data: {data: f}
```

This will produce the POST parameters like so:

```
data={"number":"value of number","location:...}
```

However, there is not reason to create JSON here. I would sent the values as normal post parameters. For that you just create an object like above and assign it to `data`:

```
data: {street: street, location: location, number: number}
```

This will create the POST parameters:

```
street=valueofstreet&location=valueoflocation&...
```

This would be easier as you don't have to parse the JSON at the server side.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send a JSON formatted request to the server you could specify the proper content type for this request and then use the `JSON.stringify` method:

```
var street = $('#street').val();
var location = $('#location').val();
var number = $('#number').val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/orders',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ street: street, location: location, number: number }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (l) { 
        alert("Done");
    }
});
```

This will send the following in the POST body:

```
{ street: 'foo', location: 'bar', number: 'baz' }
```

Obviously the server side script you are sending this AJAX to need to be capable of handling and parsing JSON strings.

Comment: Only very recent browsers provide a JSON object. You really should include a library that provides one for slightly older browsers if you do this.

Comment: @David Dorward, that's correct and an important thing to point out.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var f = {}
    f['street'] = $("#street").val();
    f['location'] = $("#location").val();
    f['number'] = $("#number").val();
```

Comment: Thank you, how about addresss block? How is that possible... like addresss block and order block into f varible?

Comment: By default jQuery will encode this as application/x-www-form-urlencoded not application/json data.

Comment: @user622378: you can add another key in f variable to store value that can be an object like f
`var add = {};
add['street'] = 'streat';
f['address'] = add ;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var f = {
        "street": street,
        "location": location,
        "number": number
        };
```

Comment: By default jQuery will encode this as application/x-www-form-urlencoded not application/json data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify` from [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

Don't forget to specify `contentType: 'application/json'` in your config object.

Answer (score 0):

try this. values will be replaced respectively

`{street : street,location : location, number : number}`

Comment: By default jQuery will encode this as application/x-www-form-urlencoded not application/json data.