# Python Regex to pull multiple pieces of data out of a data structure

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I need a regex to pull tidbits out of the following data structure.  This data is in a javascript variable.  I'm using BeautifulSoup and Mechanize to make the request and parse the page but I don't see how I can get what I need without a regex.  More details follow below.

raw data:

```
var d = [[909.0546875,842.3125,32429,'TownID: 32429','GREY','circle_grey.png',970,'goldpimp\'s city','','N/A'],[1434.8890625,1365.41484375,32143,'TownID: 32143','GREY','circle_grey.png',899,'1..','','N/A'],[1553.92265625,1117.43046875,32326,'TownID: 32326','GREY','circle_grey.png',522,'Avacyns Pantheon','','N/A'],[1305.17265625,1328.6421875,28927,'TownID: 28927','GREY','circle_grey.png',3554,'Furiocity','','N/A'],...(cont.)
```

For example on the first line I need to pull `TownID: 32429`, `970`, and `goldpimp\'s city`

I need to do this for the whole data structure to get each townID and associated information.  Sorry for the newbie question but regex really racks my brain.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I eventually got this working by parsing out the script tags then making bash calls to use sed/awk/grep/tr to clean things up and output to the command line. I know its a ghetto way of doing things but I wrote the main script to do all the getting and script tag parsing, and then I wrote another script to call the first one with the command line options to do the final parsing. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

`d` is a list, you can access lists by indexing. So, why the regex? You don't need it.
For getting your result:

```
for city in d:
  print "%s %s %s" % (city[3], city[6], city[7])
```

The `print` statement prints the text in console. Each `%s` will be replaced (in order) with a string from the right group (first `%s` will be replaced with `city[3]`, second with `city[6]` and third with `city[7]`).

*EDIT*

OK, if `d` comes from a Javascript source, you need to convert to Python data using `json.loads`, store the result of it in a variable and access with the eariler method (see info about the Python's `json` module [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) for 2.7 and [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html) for 3.3).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any pointers on how to jsonify the variable?

Comment: Maybe a peek from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793540/how-to-convert-variables-into-json)?

Comment: Thank you, I eventually got this working using bash calls to clean up the output. While I find it acceptable to use bash calls in a python script, the fact that I wrote a second script to call the first one seems a bit ghetto but hey, it may be a hack but it works!